# In Objective-c what I should use to return that parameter can't be nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, nserror, nsexception

I know that I can return that parameter can't be nil by NSError or throw NSException, but what is the best option to inform that parameter can't be nil in objective-c ?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation.

Use assertions to raise exceptions during development.

Return an `NSError` too (though it should hopefully never happen by the time you get to production).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSAssert()`, which will only fire in builds where `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` is not defined:

```
- (void)someMethodWithParam:(id)someParam {
    NSAssert(someParam, @"someParam cannot be nil");
    ...
}
```

That will pretty much restrict the checking to you, and fellow developers, but if you want it to persist, regardless of build, then an `NSException` is best:

```
- (void)someMethodWithParam:(id)someParam {
    if (!someParam) {
        [NSException raise:@"MyException" format:@"someParam cannot be nil"];
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: NSParameterAssert would be more appropriate here

Answer (score 0):

To check at compile time use

```
__attribute__ with nonnull
```

Example, first and second parameters should not be null:

```
extern void * my_memcpy (void *dest, const void *src, size_t len) 
__attribute__((nonnull (1, 2)));
```

> The nonnull attribute specifies that some function parameters should
>   be non-null pointers. Using nonnull encodes expectations about values
>   into an explicit contract, which can help catch any NULL pointer bugs
>   lurking in any calling code. Remember: compile-time errors ≫ run-time
>   errors.

Read more [here](http://nshipster.com/__attribute__/)